# Does $f(x)$ is continuous and $f = 0$ a.e. imply $f=0$ everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I wanna prove that

"if $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and satisfies $f=0$ almost everywhere (in the sense of Lebesgue measure), then, $f=0$ everywhere."

I am confident that the statement is true, but stuck with the proof. Also, is the statement true if the domain $\mathbb{R}^n$ is restricted to $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ that contains a neighborhood of the origin "$0$"?

Comment: Try that $f=0$ a.e. implies that $f^{-1}(0)$ is dense.  Then use continuity.

Comment: Or, suppose that there's a point where $f$ is nonzero, say $f(x)=a>0$. What can you say about the values that $f$ takes on small enough balls around $x$?

Comment: Let $B(x,r)\subset\Omega$. Then the average of $f$ over this ball is $$\frac{1}{|B(x,r)|}\int_{B(x,r)} f(y)\,dy=0$$ since $f$ vanishes a.e. Then taking $r\to0$, continuity shows that the limit is exactly $f(x)$.

Comment: sos440, a candidate for http://mathoverflow.net/questions/42512/awfully-sophisticated-proof-for-simple-facts?

Comment: @JonasMeyer, I cannot understand why you refer to my proof as *overly sophiscated*, for I think this is among the most direct way to utilize the property of measure-zero.

Comment: @sos440: Sorry, I exaggerated. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is a generalization of the result that you want:

> > **Theorem:** Let $f,g$ be two continuous functions such that $f = g$ a.e. Then $f = g$ everywhere.
> >
> > **Proof:** Let $E$ be the set of all $x$ such that $f(x) \neq g(x)$. Suppose $E$ is not empty and so contains some $x$. Then $E$ being the complement of a closed set is open and so we can find $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B_\epsilon(x) \subseteq E$. But now this means
> >     $$0 < \mu(B_\epsilon(x)) \leq \mu(E)$$
> >     contradicting $\mu(E) = 0$. It follows that $E$ has to be empty so that $f = g$ everywhere.

Comment: I don't quite understand the second part of your proof. Would you please explain that for me? Thanks@Grothendieck

Comment: @Yang The fact that $\{x\mid f(x) = g(x)\}$ is closed holds for mappings on Hausdorff spaces.

Answer (score 13):

A set of measure zero has dense complement.  So if a continuous function zero on a set of full measure, it is identically zero.

Answer (score 7):

Since $f$ is continuous, if $f(\hat{x}) \neq 0$, then there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)|> \frac{1}{2}|f(\hat{x})|$ for $x \in B_\infty(\hat{x},\delta)$. Since $m(B_\infty(\hat{x},\delta)) = (2 \delta)^n>0$, we see that if $f(\hat{x}) \neq 0$, there exists a set of positive measure on which $f$ is non-zero.

Hence if $f$ is zero a.e., it must be zero everywhere.

(I choose the '$\infty$' ball so I could compute the measure easily.)

Comment: could you please explain for me in detail where the $|f(x)|>\frac{1}{2}|f(\hat{x})|$ part comes from? I'm trying to work this problem out on my own, but I don't understand how this part comes from continuity. Perhaps if you could show me how to derive it from the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition of continuity...

Comment: The function $x \mapsto |f(x)|$ is continuous at $\hat{x}$ so if I let $\epsilon = {1 \over 2} |f(\hat{x})|$ (which is $>0$ by assumption), then there is some $\delta>0$ such that if $x \in B_\infty(\hat{x},\delta)$ then $|f(x)-f(\hat{x})| < \epsilon$. Since $|a-b| \ge |a|-|b|$, we have $|f(\hat{x})| < \epsilon + |f({x})|$, or $|f(x)| > |f(\hat{x})| - \epsilon$.  Now substitute the chosen value of $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 4):

This is another simpler but longer approach.

Notice that it is enough to show that $|f|=0$ everywhere, so let's assume that $f$ is nonnegative.

Since $f=0$ a.e. it follows that
$$\int_{\Bbb R^n} f=0.$$
Divide the entire space $\Bbb R^n$ in nonoverlapping cubes of side length 1, say $\{I_k\}_{k\in\Bbb N}$, then
$$0=\int_{\Bbb R^n} f=\sum_{k\in\Bbb N} \int_{I_k} f$$
and then
$$\int_{I_k} f=0$$
for each $k\in\Bbb N$. That's the key of this proof.

---

**Lemma.** *Let $f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$ be a continuous nonnegative function. Let $I=[a^1,b^1]\times\cdots\times [a^n,b^n]$ be an interval. If*
$$\int_I f=0,$$
*then*
$$f(x)=0$$
*for each $x\in I$.*

*Proof.* The proof is by induction on $n$.

If $n=1$ it is just [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/102537/8271).

Suppose that the result holds for $1,\ldots,n-1$. Notice that Fubini's theorem is applicable, so
$$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\x}{\mathbf{x}}
\int_I f(\x)\d\x=\int_{a^n}^{b^n}\left[\int_{a^{n-1}}^{b^{n-1}}\cdots \int_{a^{1}}^{b^{1}} f\left(x^1,\ldots,x^n\right)\d x^{1}\cdots \d x^{n-1}\right]\d x^{n}.\tag{1}\label{eqi}$$
Define $K:\left[a^n,b^n\right]\to\Bbb R$ by
$$K(t)=\left[\int_{a^{n-1}}^{b^{n-1}}\cdots \int_{a^{1}}^{b^{1}} f\left(x^1,\ldots,t\right)\d x^{1}\cdots \d x^{n-1}\right].$$
The LHS of \ref{eqi} is $0$, so $K$ is $0$ a.e. in $\left[a^n,b^n\right]$. Since $K$ is continuous in $\left[a^n,b^n\right]$, by our hypothesis follows that $K$ is $0$ identically  in $\left[a^n,b^n\right]$.

Now, fix $t\in \left[a^n,b^n\right]$. By Fubini again
$$\int_{[a^1,b^1]\times\cdots\times [a^{n-1},b^{n-1}]} f\left(x^1,\ldots,x^{n-1},t\right)\d \left(x^1,\ldots,x^{n-1}\right)=K(t)=0,$$
by our induction hypothesis, it follows that
$$f\left(x^1,\ldots,x^{n-1},t\right)=0$$
for each $\left(x^1,\ldots,x^{n-1}\right)\in [a^1,b^1]\times\cdots\times [a^{n-1},b^{n-1}]$. Since $t\in \left[a^n,b^n\right]$ is arbitrary it follows that
$$f\left(x^1,\ldots,x^{n}\right)=0$$
for each $\left(x^1,\ldots,x^{n}\right)\in I$, as we wanted.

---

Then using the Lemma, it follows that $f$ is $0$ everywhere in each $I_k$ and therefore $f$ is identically $0$.

Comment: Nice answer! I would rather use subscripts than superscripts though!

Answer (score 0):

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. If $f=0$ a.e. then $f=0$.
Proof. Let $f$ be as stated. Then there is a measurable set $N$ such that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n-N$ and $\mu(N)=0.$ 
Let $x_0\in N.$ Since $\mu(N)=0$, there is no open ball contained in $N$, otherwise, let's say $B\subseteq N$, one has $0<\mu(B)\leq\mu(N)=0$. Hence for all $\varepsilon>0$, $B(x_0,\varepsilon)\not\subseteq N$. This implies that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists $x_n\in N^c$ such that $x_n\in B(x_0,1/n)$, and thus $(x_n)\rightarrow x_0$. Moreover, since $x_n\in N^c,$ $f(x_n)=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}.$ 
Hence by the continuity of $f$, $f(x_0)=f(\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n)=0$.