# Prove that $\int_{I}f=0 \iff$ the function $f\colon I\to \Bbb R$ is identically $0$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, integration

Let $I$ be a generalized rectangle in $\Bbb R^n$

Suppose that the function $f\colon I\to \Bbb R$ is continuous. Assume that $f(x)\ge 0$, $\forall x \in I$

Prove that $\int_{I}f=0 \iff$ the function $f\colon I\to \Bbb R$ is identically $0$.

---

My idea is that

For $(\impliedby)$

Since $f\colon I\to \Bbb R$ is identically zero, $$f(I)=0$$

Then $$\int_{I}f=\int 0=0$$

For $(\implies)$,

Since $f$ is continuous, the function is integrable.

i.e $\int _{I} f $ exists.

---

I need the show that $\int f=0$ but how?

Hopefully, other solution is true. Please check this. And how to continue this? Thank you:)

Comment: Please note that "identically" is spelled "identically".

Comment: Dear @dfeuer what?

Comment: You spelled it "identiacally". That was wrong. You did it three times, so it was most likely a systematic error rather than a random one.

Comment: This is precisely the Lemma [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/259636/8271)

Comment: Oh! I didnt pay any attention. Sorry. I guess because of keybord dictionary.  Thank you :) @dfeuer

Comment: I've posted a related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453580/might-proof-by-contradiction-be-needed-for-this-mundane-problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One direction is obvious. If $f$ is identically $0$, the integral is zero. Now suppose $f$ is continuous but **not** identically zero. Then there exists a point in $I$ such that $f(\xi)>0$. By continuity there exists a neighborhood of $\xi$ where $f(x)>0$ whenever $x\in(\xi-\delta,\xi+\delta)$. Can you take it from here?

Since $f\geqslant 0$, it follows that $$\int_I f \geq \int_{(\xi-\delta,\xi+\delta)} f>0$$

Thus, we have proven the contrapositive.

Comment: No. Please can you continue from here? Thank you.

Comment: I want to learn incorrect. And I dont know how to reach the solution by using the definiton of continouty ?

Comment: Okay Iunderstand thanks:)

Comment: Hi, Dear @PeterTamaroff can you help me to solve this question as well? Thank you:) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453678/fundamental-optimization-question-consisting-of-two-parts

Answer (score 4):

This may be only a minor variation on an earlier answer, but maybe it adds something.

Suppose there's some point $x_0$ where $f(x_0)>0$.  Let $\varepsilon=f(x_0)/2$.  Then by continuity, there is some $\delta>0$ such that for $x$ in the open interval with endpoints $x_0\pm\delta$, the distance between $f(x)$ and $f(x_0)$ is less than $\varepsilon$.  That means $f(x)>f(x_0)/2$ on that interval.  Hence
$$
\int_{x_0-\delta}^{x_0+\delta} f(x)\,dx > 2\delta\cdot\frac{f(x_0)}{2} = \delta f(x_0)>0.
$$

Maybe one reason I feel I ought to post this is that there is a question: intuitively, the statement that if a function is positive on an interval, then its integral over that interval is postive, seems obvious.  But how does one prove it without doing something like what I did above?  What I did gives a partition of the interval, $\{a,x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta,b\}$, where $a,b$ are the endpoints, for which the lower Riemann sum is positive.  Or if you like Lebesgue's definition, it gives a simple function dominated by $f$, whose integral is positive.

Comment: Crisp and clear answer =)

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $f(x)>0$ for some $x\in I$, as $f$ is continuous $\exists\ \delta>0$ such that $\forall y\in B_\delta(x)\cap I$, we will have $f(y)>0$. Then, as $f(x)\ge 0$

$$\displaystyle\int_If\ge\displaystyle\int_{B_\delta(x)\cap I}f>0 \implies\text{contradiction}$$.

Comment: A downvote? Why?

Comment: The downvote was probably because your answer is unclear.

Comment: @dfeuer I think it is clear, but I would choose another name for $x$.