# Might proof by contradiction be needed for this mundane problem?

Tags: real-analysis, logic

This present question is inspired by [this earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453502/prove-that-int-if-0-iff-the-function-f-colon-i-to-bbb-r-is-identically).

Consider the problem of proving that if $f\ge 0$ on an interval $I\subseteq\mathbb R$ and $\int_I f=0$, then $f$ is $0$ (almost) everywhere on $I$.

Can it be proved that the only way to prove this is by contradiction?

**PS:** How about if we consider two cases: (1) $f$ is continuous (and then disregard the word "almost"); (2) $f$ is measurable.

Comment: @GitGud : Further edited accordingly.

Comment: It's usually proved by contraposition, no?

Comment: I don't think this question is answerable without first specifying precisely what axiomatic system we're working in, and which deduction rules in the underlying logic are deemed to be proofs-by-contradiction.

Comment: In the first case, the point of proving it by contradiction is to find a point $a\in I$ such that $f(a)\neq 0$ and then proceed using continuity.

This can be avoided by considering the logical truth:
$$\text{there exists }a\in I \text{ such that }f(a)\neq 0\lor f \text{ is the null function}.$$

This of course assumes that the above statement is in fact a logical truth, but that's dependent on the [law of excluded middle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle) which is equivalent to the [principle of noncontradiction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_non-contradiction).

Comment: @GitGud Constructivists would be very surprised to hear that the law of excluded middle (which they reject) is equivalent to the principle of noncontradiction (which they accept). The former says that *at least one* of the two propositions $p$, $\neg p$ is true; the latter says that *at most one* of those two propositions is true.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I wasn't sure about what I was saying, so I googled it, misread something and ultimately made the mistake you pointed out. Thanks.

Comment: What about this: Define $F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)\, dt$. Since $f\ge 0$, we have $0\le F(x)\le\int_0^1 f(t)\,dt=0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. Thus $F$ is identically $0$ on $[0,1]$. Since $f$ is continuous, we have $F'(x)=f(x)=0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass By the way, above I meant [double negation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negation) instead of LOM.

Comment: Lebesgue Differentiation for question (2)?

Comment: @GitGud The law of double negation, specifically the half of it that says "if not not p then p," is. like LEM, rejected in constructive logic, and is in fact constructively equivalent to LEM.  The other half of double negation ("if p then not not p") and the law of non-contradiction ("not both p and not p") are constructively valid.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I'm sorry for making so many mistakes, what I meant was DN instead of PofnonC. I'm actualy thinking right, just writing the wrong things. I meant DN instead of PofnonC from the start, which is the relevant thing to mention because the OP is looking for a proof without contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Without contradiction:

For every $n\geqslant1$, let $B_n=\{x\in I\mid nf(x)\geqslant1\}$, then $0\leqslant\mathbf 1_{B_n}\leqslant nf$ (this step uses the hypothesis that $f\geqslant0$ everywhere on $I$) hence $0\leqslant\mathrm{Leb}(B_n)\leqslant n\int\limits_If=0$, which implies that $\mathrm{Leb}(B_n)=0$. Now, the set $B=\{x\in I\mid f(x)\ne0\}$ is $B=\bigcup\limits_{n\geqslant1}B_n$ hence $\mathrm{Leb}(B)\leqslant\sum\limits_{n\geqslant1}\mathrm{Leb}(B_n)=0$, QED.