# Prove $\int _a^b |f(t)| \, dt $ is a norm

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $a < b$ be real numbers and $X = C[a,b]$ be the space of continuous functions $f : [a,b] → \mathbb R$. Prove that $$ \|f \|_1 =\int _a^b |f(t)|\,dt $$indeed deﬁnes a norm on $X$.

Struggling on $\|f\|_1=0 \iff f=0$.

For the backward direction, it seems easy but the forward is not really obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\int_a^b |f(x)|dx = 0$, then $\phi(t) = \int_a^t |f(x)|dx = 0$ for all
$t$, and so $\phi'(t) = 0 = |f(t)|$.

To see why $\phi$ is zero, note that the integral of a non negative quantity must be non negative. Hence $\phi(t) \ge 0$ for all $t$. Also, if $a,b$ are
non negative quantities, then if $a+b = 0$ we must have $a=b=0$.

Since $\phi(b) = \int_a^b |f(x)|dx = 0 = \phi(t) + \int_t^b |f(x)|dx $, we see
that we must have $\phi(t) = 0$.

Comment: could you elaborate on how phi dash of t is 0

Comment: and how phi dash t is even equal to |f(t)|

Comment: @snowman: Since $\phi$ is constant (in fact $\phi(t) = 0$ for all $t$), then the derivative must be zero. The fundamental theorem of calculus shows that $\phi'(t) = |f(t)|$.

Comment: Oh, that's clever :-)

Comment: @copper.hat I understand how the phi is a constant function but could you explain how it is zero

Comment: @snowman: I added a note to the answer, hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $\left\Vert f\right\Vert =0$ but $f\neq0$. Recall that compositions
of continuous functions (e.g. $|\cdot|\circ f$) are continuous. Use
the continuity of $t\mapsto|f(t)|$ to establish the existence of
an interval $I\subset[a,b]$ on which $|f(t)|\geq M$ for some $M>0$.
This yields the desired contradiction since
$$
\left\Vert f\right\Vert =\int_{a}^{b}|f(t)|dt\geq\int_{I}|f(t)|dt\geq\int_{I}Mdt>0.
$$

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you already know how to show homogeneity, triangle inequality and $f = 0 \implies \lVert f \rVert_1$.

Observe that if $\lVert f \rVert_1 = 0$, then $f$ must be $0$ almost everywhere. Then $f = 0$ since [continuous functions agreeing a.e. are equal.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231103/does-fx-is-continuous-and-f-0-a-e-imply-f-0-everywhere)

Comment: You surely mean "are equal" in that last phrase.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Thanks. It is fixed.