# Is my solution correct to prove that $f (x) = 0$ for all $x \in [a, b]$?

Tags: real-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$f\geq 0$ and $\int_a^b f=0$ implies $f=0$ everywhere on $[a,b]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102476/f-geq-0-and-int-ab-f-0-implies-f-0-everywhere-on-a-b)

[image]

Is this a correct solution?

Thanks for your help

Comment: It is correct, and the usual way to show this problem.

Comment: Looks correct and pretty nice.

Comment: Was going to ask for the source, but then I realized this was from baby Rudin.

Comment: A nitpick, $\delta > 0$ and $\delta < \min(x_0-a, b-x_0)$ to be completely sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is another approach (I prefer 'constructive' proofs, albeit they tend to be longer, as is the case here):

Since $\int f = 0$, and $f$ is continuous, we have $\int f = \sup_{\pi \in {\cal P}} L(f,\pi) = 0$, where ${\cal P}$ is the set of partitions of $[a,b]$, and $L(f,\pi)$ is the Riemann sum. Since $[a,b]$ is compact, $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Let $\epsilon>0$. Choose $\delta>0$ so that if $|x-y| < \delta$, then $|f(x)-f(y) | < \epsilon$. Choose a partition $\pi$ with $\text{mesh } \pi < \delta$. Since $f \geq 0$, we have $L(f,\pi) = 0$, and hence on every subinterval $[x,y]$ of $\pi$, we have some $\xi$ such that $f(\xi) = 0$. Uniform continuity shows that $f(t) < \epsilon$ for all $t \in [x,y]$. Hence $f(t) < \epsilon$ for all $t \in [a,b]$. Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, we are finished.

Comment: Great proof. One (little) thing I can comment on is that the subintervals of $\pi$ don't have to be of the form $[x,y]$ but can also have the form $(x,y]$ or $(x,y)$ etc. But this is no problem since the length of the intervals do not change by removing or adding single points.

Comment: @André: A partition is of the form $\pi=(x_0=a,x_1,...,x_n=b)$ and the intervals formed from the partition are $[x_i, x_{i+1}]$, all of which are closed.