# Continuous $f$ has $≥2$ roots if $\int_{-1}^{1} f(x)\sqrt {1 - x^2}\ \mathrm{d}x = \int_{-1}^{1} xf(x)\ \mathrm{d}x = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, roots

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[-1, 1]$ such that $$\int_{-1}^{1} f(x)\sqrt {1 - x^2}\ \mathrm{d}x = 0\ = \int_{-1}^{1} xf(x)\ \mathrm{d}x\ .$$

Prove that the equation $f(x) = 0$ has at least two real roots in $(-1, 1)$.

I am not sure where to begin, but I am thinking that I need to squeeze out the integral of $f(x)$ on $[-1, 1]$, although I am not sure if that is relevant to this problem. I was also taught that if I needed to prove "at least (*insert number*) real roots", one would usually use the Intermediate Value Theorem, but I am not sure how to apply that here. Perhaps, is it possible/wise to determine what $f(x)$ is and proceed from there?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is positive in $(-1,1)$ then $\int_{-1}^{1} f(x)\sqrt {1 - x^2} dx = 0$ implies that the continuous function $f$ has at least a zero $a\in (-1,1)$ (otherwise the product $f(x)\sqrt {1 - x^2}$ has the same sign over $(-1,1)$ and, recalling that [*if $F\geq 0$ is continuous and $\int_a^b F(x)\,dx=0$ then $F=0$ everywhere in $[a,b]$*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102476/f-geq-0-continuous-and-int-ab-f-0-implies-f-0-everywhere-on-a-b), we have a contradiction.

Assume that $a$ is the unique root of $f$ in $(-1,1)$, then $f$ should be positive on one side of $a$ and negative on the other side. Moreover
$$\int_{-1}^{1} f(x)g(x)\,dx=0$$
where $g(x)=(x\sqrt{1 - a^2}-a\sqrt {1 - x^2})$ is a continuous function which is negative in $[-1,a)$ and positive in $(a,1]$. Hence the product $fg$ has the same sign on $(-1,1)$, and, since its integral is zero, we have a contradiction.

Comment: May I know how you to the conclusion that $f$ has at least one zero in $(-1, 1)$? I am not sure I follow your logic for the first sentence, so I am unable to move on.

Comment: Otherwise $f(x)\sqrt {1 - x^2}$ is always positive or always negative in $(-1,1)$ and therefore its integral can't be zero.

Comment: Ah. In other words we are trying to observe that $f$ cannot be always positive or negative in $(-1, 1)$, am I correct?

Comment: @EthanMark Yes, that's correct!

Comment: @EthanMark Are you able now to show that the roots are at least 2?

Comment: May I know how you were able to “cook up” $g$? Is there some intuition behind it?

Comment: I just tried to exploit the same idea we used to show the existence of at least one root.

Comment: @EthanMark I included more details. I hope it is clear now!

Comment: Your logic is great, but why do you say $f=0$ a contradiction, it makes a possible case, i think you should edit there. Otherwise it looks very good(+1).

Comment: @Alearner Do you mean here: " implies =0 everywhere on [,] , we have a contradiction."? I edited my answer. Is it better now?

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract both integrals to get $$\int_{-1}^1 f(x)(x-\sqrt{1-x^2})dx=0,$$ define $$h(t):=\int_{-1}^t f(x)(x-\sqrt{1-x^2})dx$$ and notice that $h(-1)=h(1)=0$.

Comment: That would show that $h$ has two zeros, but how do I infer the same of $f$?

Comment: Then $h$ is zero at $-1$ and $1$. How is this related with the two roots of $f$ in $(-1,1)$?

Comment: @Ethan Mark use Rolle's theorem.

Comment: @Alearner Rolle's Theorem gives one root the question is asking for 2.

Comment: @N. S. Yeah! You are right. This answer doesn't fulfill the requirement.